# Can I force an email client (Thunderbird) to redownload autoconfig info?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I created an [autoconfig file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration) for Thunderbird. And it was ok.
Thunderbird downloaded it when I created an account.

Then I changed this file and tried to create an account again. But Thunderbird doesn't even make a request to a HTTP server to check this file. It just uses something from it's cache. (Tried to restart TB)

Where is this information stored? Is the only way for Thunderbird to update autoconfig info - to find this cache and remove it?

Comment: Did you try to delete the profile? Start it with the `-profilemanager` option to manage profiles.

Comment: well, yes, new profile helps... but.. really? delete profile each time? Profile can have several mail boxes